# Access a list from an object in dart

Tags: dart

I come from as3 environment, so I am big beginner in dart and HTML.

I have this variable

```js
var symbols = [
               {"name":"first",
                 "num":[2,2,3]
               }];
```

I want to access num array and save it to variable, I try to do this:

```js
var symbol = symbols[0];
var num = symbol.num;
```

I get

```js
Breaking on exception: Class '_LinkedHashMap' has no instance getter 'num'.
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is a list of a map of String to String. You could write the type like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> symbols;
```

so naturally what you want to access is the value for the key "num". You can do this:

```
symbols[0]['num']
```

but it doesn't automatically gets mapped to an instance variable by writing:

```
symbol.num
```

If you had a class like this, the above would work:

```
class Symbol {
    var num;
}
```

Comment: One thing to change is the type you have listed. It should be List<Map<String, dynamic>> instead of List<Map<String, String>>.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work this way in Dart.
Try:

```dart
symbols[0]['num']
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript style of "object" access doesn't work in Dart.  Switch this line:

```
var num = symbol.num;
```

with:

```
var num = symbol["num"];
```

See [the `[]` operator in the documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Map#id_[]).